# how to translate a java object to a map in clojure？

Tags: java, clojure

For example:

```java
class Person {
    String name;
}
```

I would like to get `{:name "xxx}` from an instance of Person.

I know `(from_json (.toJson person))` can do it.

Is there any better way to achieve it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you seen the [bean](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/bean) function? The example code above doesn't follow the JavaBean rules, but if your objects do (using getters), then bean will turn it into a Clojure map for you.

```java
public class Person {
  private String name;
  public Person(String n) {
    this.name = n;
  }
  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }
}
```

Use like this:

```clj
(def p (Person. "xyz"))
(bean p)
;=> {:name "xyz" :class Person}
```

Comment: I am trying it. It will add one additional field ":class xxx.classname". Is there some parameter to prevent this field?

Comment: or there will be errors like:can't serialize class  xxx.classname.If I use dissoc ,I must try to remove the ":class" recursively.

Comment: I am trying to insert it to mongodb,so :class is not needed.

Comment: Because getClass() satisfies the bean patterns, it will automatically be included. You can dissoc it as you suggest - why not just do so when you would call bean?

Answer (score 0):

Some years ago I wrote a little library that does exactly that.

https://github.com/joodie/clj-java-fields/